# Shell Script add column values

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have  a text file which contains like below:

```
{"userId":"f1fcab","count":"3","type":"Stack"}
{"userId":"fcab","count":"2","type":"Stack"}
{"userId":"abcd","count":"5","type":"Stack"}
```

I want to get sum of the value of count.
I am using awk to achive this like below:

```
$ awk -F "," '{print $4}' test.txt
```

How can I get only the integer type using awk and add them all.

My script should give me as

```
sum=10
```

Comment: `awk 'match($0,"count\":\"([^\"])",a){x+=a[1]}END{print "sum="x}' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming consistent use of double quote characters, you can use:

```
awk -F\" '{s += $8} END{print "sum=" s+0}' inputFile
```

This will generate:

```
sum=10
```

This works because a quote delimiter gives you the fields:

```
1 2      3 4      5 6     7 8 ...
{"userId":"f1fcab","count":"3","type":"Stack"}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try the below,

```
$ awk -F'"' '{sum = sum + $8;}END{print "sum="sum+0}' file
sum=10
```

- `-F'"'` Sets the double quotes as `FS` value. Awk splits the row into colunms according to the value of `FS` variable.
- `sum = sum + $8` Calculate the sum of all the values in column no 8 and store it into a variable called `sum`
- Finally by printing the variable `sum` at the end will give you the desired output.

Comment: Thanks Avinash..What is the use of $8

Comment: note you can say `sum+=$8` instead of `sum = sum + $8`. Also, it is sometimes handy to print `sum + 0`, so that if `sum` wasn't set, you'll get a 0.

Comment: @fedorqui `sum+0` is not needed as `+ $8` will always evaluate to an number even if there aren't 8 fields.If the field isn't a number or doesn't exist it is set to 0.

Comment: @Jidder interesting, good to know! I tested and you are right. Then, the edge case that `+0` solves is when the `sum` wasn't executed at all. That is, `awk '{sum+=$2} END {print sum}' file` will fail if the file is empty; also, if the sum is within a condition that is never matched.

Comment: @fedorqui suppose, don't know why you'd want to do it on an empty file though. You can also just do `+sum` instead although i'm not sure if this is supported by all awks.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the value of `count` key using double quotes (`"`) as delimiter so that the eighth column will be the value to `count` on:

```
$ awk -F"\"" 'BEGIN {sum=0} {sum+=$8} END {print sum}' fd
10
```

Comment: Just one suggestion, `"` is a _double_ quote.

Comment: `BEGIN` block is not needed, since `sum` is nothing at start and does not need to be declared. So this should do: `awk -F\" '{sum+=$8} END {print sum}'`.  And then it would just be the same as paxdiablo posted.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'[:"]' '{sum+=$10} END{print "sum=" sum}' File
```

Setting **':'** and **'"'** as delimiters. Then taking the 10th field, which is the count value. add then up to sum and print at the end.

Example:

```
sdlcb@ubuntu:~/AMD_C/SO$ cat File
{"userId":"f1fcab","count":"3","type":"Stack"}
{"userId":"fcab","count":"2","type":"Stack"}
{"userId":"abcd","count":"5","type":"Stack"}
sdlcb@ubuntu:~/AMD_C/SO$ awk -F'[:"]' '{sum+=$10} END{print "sum=" sum}' File
sum=10
```